# Array of pointers remaining null despite being directly set

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, nullptr

I have a list of 'cell' objects in a 2d array of length [sizeX][sizeY]. These `Cell` objects contain an array of type `*Cell`, which should point to each of the given cell's adjacent cells in the format North, East, South, West (Never Eat Soggy Waffles).

This array is called `compass`, and is defined with a length of 4. After the cells have been initialized (at which time all values of `compass` are set to `nullptr`), I have a loop which attempts to fill `Cell.compass` with pointers to the appropriate nearby cells.

However, I have found that despite all this, in each cell I have found that `compass` still is full of null values.

In this loop, I also run a function `Cell::computeTopology()` which populates a vector (which is a property of `Cell`) of the valid non-null indexes of `compass`. This is similarly empty.

I have made a breakpoint both before and after this function has been called to the exact same effect. Regardless I will include this function as well. I'm utterly perplexed and some help here would be greatly appreciated.

Problem area:

```
  const int sizeX = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCALE;
    const int sizeY = SCREEN_HEIGHT / SCALE;
    Cell cells[sizeX][sizeY];
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++){
            cells[x][y].setPos(x, y);
            cells[x][y] = Cell();
            //cells[x][y].setColor(rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255);
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++) {
            Cell c = cells[x][y];
            if (x - 1 >= 0) {

                c.compass[3] = &cells[x - 1][y];
            }
            if (x + 1 < (SCREEN_WIDTH / SCALE)) {

                c.compass[1] = &cells[x + 1][y];

            }
            if (y - 1 >= 0) {

                c.compass[0] = &cells[x][y - 1];

            }
            if (y + 1 < (SCREEN_HEIGHT / SCALE)) {

                c.compass[2] = &cells[x][y + 1];
            }
            c.computeTopology();
        }
    }
```

And the `computeTopology()` function

```
void Cell::computeTopology()
{
    int i = 0;
    for (Cell *c : compass) {
        if (c != nullptr) {
            notNull.push_back(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Cell c = cells[x][y]; // make a copy
```

to

```
Cell& c = cells[x][y];
```

you want to modify item of array, not copy.

Another issue

```
cells[x][y].setPos(x, y);
cells[x][y] = Cell(); // ?
```

you are setting some members of `cells[x][y]` by calling `setPos` and after it you are overwriting `cells[x][y]` by default constructed `Cell` object. I think the second line in above code should be removed.

---

Your words

> which populates a vector (which is a property of Cell) of the **valid**
>   **non-null indexes** of compass

so `i` index should be advanced with every iteration of for loop:

```
  int i = 0;
  for (Cell *c : compass) {
        if (c != nullptr) {
            notNull.push_back(i);
        }
        ++i; // moved
  }
```

Comment: Well we also don't know what `cells[x][y] = Cell();` does.  After he calls `cells[x][y].setPos(x,y)` he could be wiping it out with that call.

Comment: Yes I am aware that cells[x][y] = Cell(); is redundant but I was just trying to cover all bases... thanks though. your answer makes a lot of sense.Gonna try it rn

Comment: also setpos doesnt actually do anything anymore. this is a very large project and unfortunately yeah there is quite a bit of fluff that needs to be cleaned. THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: Eh although your correction to the first set of code was correct, by "valid non-null indexes" I meant the indexes of compass that did result in nullpointers. My code works as intended with computeTopology as it was, and I feel like my specifications were worded pretty clearly.

Comment: @DrewCarlisle I suppose compass has 4 elements, then you want to store indices to pointers which are not null, so incrementing `i` only if c is not null, is incorrect. `[][not-null][][not-null]`, so you want to store 1 and 3, not 0 and 1. Or I have misunderstood something.

Comment: I always want to increment i, because I want to store the indexes as they relate to compass. (in laymans terms I want to save the indexes that I can reliably reference in compass - its the only way I can tell if my cell is on the upper left corner or the upper right for example)